# How to check if all the tables in database are modified after an Update activity is performed on columns of tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to update all the tables having column name like '%DIV%' with a value DD wherever it is MG , I have written the script for it , but I am not getting the idea of how to verify if columns of all the tables are updated to value DD after the activity is performed. I have written this query .

```
SELECT 'SELECT '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||', '||COLUMN_NAME||' FROM '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||' WHERE '||COLUMN_NAME||' = ''MG'' ;'
FROM RADHA.CHANGE_TABLE
WHERE VALID_FLAG='Y'
```

I was planning to make a table structure like

```
OWNER  TABLE_NAME  PREV_COUNT
```

The PREV_COUNT  will hold the count of rows having Column Value as MG and after the activity is performed , I will verify with following query if the corresponding rows have been updated to DD .

```
SELECT 'SELECT '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||', '||COLUMN_NAME||' FROM '||OWNER||'.'||TABLE_NAME||' WHERE '||COLUMN_NAME||' = ''DD'' ;' FROM RADHA.CHANGE_TABLE WHERE VALID_FLAG='Y'
```

And the output of this query would go into table

```
 OWNER  TABLE_NAME  NEW_COUNT
```

But I am not able to get how to fetch records from the Select query as it is the string which is written inside the select query but I want the result set such that I can insert the records in my table mentioned above, please guide how to approach further

Comment: You need to use [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables, but - based on Scott's sample schema, here's a script which search through all its tables for a column named `JOB` (line #8) and checks how many of them have value that looks like (hint: `like`) `CLERK` in it (line #12).

See how it works, adjust it so that it works for you.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    l_str VARCHAR2(500);
  3    l_cnt NUMBER := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5    FOR cur_r IN (SELECT u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                  FROM user_tab_columns u, user_tables t
  7                  WHERE u.table_name = t.table_name
  8                    AND u.column_name = 'JOB'
  9                                                              )
 10    LOOP
 11      l_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 12               ' WHERE ' || cur_r.column_name || ' like (''%CLERK%'')';
 13
 14      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (l_str) INTO l_cnt;
 15
 16      IF l_cnt > 0 THEN
 17         dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt ||' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
 18      END IF;
 19    END LOOP;
 20  END;
 21  /
4 : EMP        --> there are 4 CLERKs in the EMP table

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want to verify my data through table only , because there are approx 1000 tables ,that is why I mentioned the table structure .

Comment: OK. Cursor's `select` will run through all tables in your schema that contain that column.

Comment: yes , but how to insert the data into the my table structure  OWNER   COLUMN_NAME   PREV_COUNT

Comment: Instead (or along with) of DBMS_OUTPUT, use INSERT into your table (line #17).

Comment: Can u plz elaborate ?

Comment: Elaborate what? How to type an insert statement? `insert into your_table (owner, column_name, prev_count) values (user, 'JOB', l_cnt');`